# Nautilus Dual Monitor issue

Tags: nautilus, multiple-monitors, apport

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and 2 monitors.
My left monitor is the laptop screen and the right monitor is an external monitor.

Whenever I open a nautilus window in my right (external) monitor and double click on some folder, it automatically moves the nautilus window to my left (laptop) monitor. This only happens on the first double click after opening a nautilus window.

Any ideas why this is happening. Though this is not critical but is an annoying bug.
Can I change some setting to avoid this behaviour. I wanted to report this as a nautilus bug. But I can't figure out how to do it through Apport.

Any help on fixing the issue would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**Update:** When I changed the monitor setup to position my external monitor to the left of my laptop monitor, the same issue gets reproduced but after the first double click the window moves to my external monitor. This makes me conclude that windows manager moves the monitor to the leftmost screen. I have also observed the same behaviour with chromium
web browser.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue in 12.04. Are you also using Gnome Classic (No effects) desktop environment? And does it happen when the nautilus window is not maximized? Or only when it is maximized? In my case only when it's maximized.

Comment: I filed a bug report at launchpad. If anyone who is affected can also indicate that there, we might get some people working on it. See at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1195725